# Continuity of a function in a locally convex topological space

Tags: general-topology, continuity, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I endow the space of bounded sequences with a locally convex topology $\tau$ such that $\tau$ is strictly finer than the product topology (the topology of pointwise convergence), $\tau_p$, and strictly weaker than the sup-norm topology (the topology of uniform convergence), $\tau_\infty$. Let $\phi:l^\infty \rightarrow l^\infty$ be defined as
$$
\phi(x_1,x_2,\dots)=(f(x_1),f(x_2),\dots)
$$
where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous (for the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$), strictly increasing and $f(0)=0$.

I proved that $\phi:(l^\infty,\tau_p) \rightarrow (l^\infty,\tau_p)$ and $\phi:(l^\infty,\tau_\infty) \rightarrow (l^\infty,\tau_\infty)$ are continuous.

Is it possible to show that $\phi:(l^\infty,\tau) \rightarrow (l^\infty,\tau)$ is continuous?